# After member function delete the current instance

Tags: c++

After member function delete the current instance，how to stop the behind code executes.
See the code.

```
#include <iostream>
class A;
void callfun(int i,A *pt);

class A {
public:
    A() { sss="this is A."; }
    virtual ~A() {}
    void foo(int i) {
        callfun(i,this);　　//call a function.Don't return value.Maybe delete instance.
        out();　　　　　　　 
    }
private:
    void out() {
        std::cout<< "Out:" <<std::endl;
        std::cout<< sss << std::endl;
    }
    std::string sss;
}

void callfun(int i,A *pt) {
    if (i==0)
        delete pt;  //If conditions are matched,delete instance.
}

int main() {
    A *a1=new A;
    a1->foo(1);     //print:Out:this is A.
    a1->foo(0);     //delete a1,don't print.But in fact it would print.how to do？
}
```

I want the result：foo(1) output "Out:this is A.",foo(0) delete instance,don't output.

Comment: Are you sure you want this? In general the cleanup of an object is not triggered by the object itself. Instead another object is given responsibility of the object and cleans it after it is not used anymore.

Comment: A member function should _never_ delete `this`, or call a function that does. That will lead to undefined behavior and bad things.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, actually there are cases when it's useful. But one needs to be VERY careful.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `delete this;` doesn't result in undefined behavior.

Comment: yes..I have to do it.Because function of "callfun" maybe finish this instance.I have considered to set close flag.this code:if (flag){out();} else {remove(this)}.It would not print output.

Comment: @Thirler,yes..I have to do it.Because function of "callfun" maybe finish this instance.I have considered to set close flag.this code:if (flag){out();} else {remove(this)}.It would not print output.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: There are thousands of Microsoft COM classes which call `delete this` in their implementation of `IUnknown::Release()`. Perfectly safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a more complete code.

```
class A;
class B {
public:
　　void creat() {
        pp=new A;
    }
    void remove() {
        delete pp;
        pp=NULL;
    }
private:
    A *pp;
};

class A {
public:
    void foo(int i) {
        callfun(i,this);　
　　　　if (flag)
            out();　　　　　　
        else 
            bb->remove();
    }
private:
    B *bb;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: this is bad. **bad**. Terrible.

```
void foo(int i) {
    if ( i == 1)  
    {
       callfun(i,this);　　//call a function.Don't return value.Maybe delete instance.
       out();　　　　　　　  
    }
    else
    {
       delete this;
    }
}
```

Note that after you've done `delete this;` (cases where this is actually needed are rare) it's illegal to call any non-`static` functions on your instance, access the pointer (both inside or outside the method) or access any data members.

Comment: The conditions don't be judge by foo. callfun is a function to handle data.

Comment: ,this function of "foo" don't know what happen when "i" get different values.

Comment: ,this function of "foo" don't know what happen when "i" get different values.

Comment: @user1641913 oh, then no, it's impossible, because you call `out` afterwards, which is a member function, so you can't delete the instance beforehand.

Comment: ,I have considered to set close flag.this code:if (flag){out();} else {remove(this)}.callfun(int i,A *pt) {if (i==0) pt->flag=false;It would not print output.But I don't know if there is a better way.

Comment: @user1641913: That's illegal. You can't test `this->flag` afterwards because `flag` is destroyed just like all other members.

Comment: @MSalters,code: if (flag){out();} else {detele this;}.this->flag can be test,then delete instance.

Comment: @user1641913: Indeed, that would also be legal.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible, given the comments which state that `foo` shouldn't be aware of the deletion. That itself make the very next line Undefined Behavior. If `callfun` calls `delete this`, then `foo` MUST return immediately without even looking at `this`. Therefore you can't even set a "deleted" flag in `this`.

The closest I get is

```
void callfun(int i, A *pt) {
  if (i==0) {
    delete pt;
    throw 0;
  }
}
void A::foo(int i) {
  try {
    callfun(i,this);　　// No _visible_ return value.
    out();　　　　　　　 
  } catch (int) { } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you delete internally, how does the enclosing scope know that its been deleted? You should just mark it and leave it up to the user/enclosing scope to actually dispose it.

Comment: this code is no all code.The class A delete instance by a class B's  member function that created instance of class A.